# Cleanly passing options between coupled shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, getopts, tightly-coupled-code

I have a (bash) shell script `myBaseScript.sh`, with the following signature:

```
myBaseScript.sh [OPTIONS] FILE1 [FILE2 ...]
```

This script `myBaseScript.sh` parses the options via `getopts`, like so:

```
while getopts ":hi:m:s:t:v:" opt; do
    #...
done

shift $(($OPTIND-1))
FILES=("$@")
```

Now I wish to create a script `mySuperScript.sh`, which calls `myBaseScript.sh`, allowing options to be forwarded to the base script:

```
mySuperScript.sh [OPTIONS] DIR1 [DIR2 ...]
```

where `[OPTIONS]` are the options used in `myBaseScript.sh`; they are *not* used in `mySuperScript.sh`.

The script `mySuperScript.sh` is to crawl through all directories `DIR1`, `[DIR2]`, etc., compiling a list of valid files `${FILES[@]}`, to be passed on to `myBaseScript.sh`.

Right now I have this in `mySuperScript.sh`:

```
myBaseScript.sh "$@" "${FILES[@]}"
```

where `${FILES[@]}` is a list of files in the *current* path. In other words, this allows for

```
mySuperScript.sh [OPTIONS]
```

but not for any optional `DIR1`, `[DIR2]`, etc.

I could use

```
allOpts=("$@")
while getopts ":hi:m:s:t:v:" opt; do echo. > /dev/null; done
shift $(($OPTIND-1))    
DIRS=("$@")
```

and then pass the first `$OPTIND` entries of `$allOpts` as `[OPTIONS]` to `myBaseScript.sh`. But that seems excessively complicated, and moreover, it necessitates *duplicating* the list of valid options to `myBaseScript.sh`, which is a managerial nightmare.

I could also create a new script, dedicated to parsing these options. But that too seems a bit awkward, as it creates a dependency in `myBaseScript.sh` which was not there before...

So, what is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your entire usecase but if your goal is simply to support both files and directories then you can just use a **single** script which checks if an argument is a directory and crawls it.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

crawl_dir() {
    dir="$1"
    find "$dir" -type f
}

# parse options
while getopts ":hi:m:s:t:v:" opt; do
    echo ...
done
shift $(($OPTIND-1))

args=( "$@" )

# parse arguments
files=()
for arg in "${args[@]}"
do
    if [[ -d "$arg" ]]
    then
        files+=( $(crawl_dir "$arg") )
    else
        files+="$arg"
    fi
done

# now you have an array of files to process
process "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Ha! A thinking-out-of-the-box idea, I like it! This can indeed be applied to my use case, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `mySuperScript.sh` with an additional marker between the `[OPTIONS]` and the list of directories:

```
mySuperScript.sh [OPTIONS] -- DIR1 [DIR2 ...]
```

Then you can iterate over the arguments and collection the options into a variable.  Something like:

```
while [ "$1" -ne "--" ]; do
  OPTIONS="$OPTIONS $1"
  shift
done
shift
```

Then you can later on call:

```
myBaseScript.sh $OPTIONS $some_list_of_files
```

This works fine as long as you're not trying to handle optional arguments containing spaces.

On a more practical note, this is generally when I start looking at Python.

Comment: Use an array to accumulate options--`OPTIONS=()` followed by `OPTIONS+=("$1")`, then use `myBaseScript.sh "${OPTIONS[@]}"`--and that problem goes away.

Comment: If you wanted to get extra tricky, you could add an option to `myBaseScript.sh` to emit a string suitable for use by `getopts`.  Your `mySuperScript.sh` would call that first, then use `getopts` to parse the command line.  You would still collect options in a variable (possibly an array, as chepner suggested) as before, but because you're actually using `getopts` you would not need the separator.

Comment: @larsks: yeah, I've been thinking about that too...bit of a hack, really, which is why I didn't even suggest it :) But if it's a choice between the cleanest shell scripts or the cleanest call from the command line, I'll think I really have to go for latter here.